# Maven multi module prroject circular dependency issue which i am unable to solve

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-plugin

I have tried the most common fixes suggested on stackkoverflow but i am still unable to solve my problem. Exclusions/dependency helpers/plugins etc.

I have a parent module and 2 sub modules which i'd like to commuunicate with eachother. module one downloads data and module 2 does some pre processing before it is stored in a databbase.

To realize this i added the dependencies to the modules itself in the parrents pom.xml this causes the problem of course but i'd figuure i could just add them and force it to ignore duplicate dependencies or something.

How else can i make the 2 modules talk communicate to eachother?
any advice or help would be really appreciated!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.algoframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>AlgoFramework</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>binance-api-custom</module>
        <module>influxdb-controller</module>
    </modules>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.algoframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>binance-api-custom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.algoframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>influxdb-controller</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>



-----------------------------------------------



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>AlgoFramework</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.algoframework</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>binance-api-custom</artifactId>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asynchttpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asynchttpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>async-http-client-extras-retrofit2</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>

-----------------------------------------------


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>AlgoFramework</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.algoframework</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>influxdb-controller</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.influxdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>influxdb-client-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.influxdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flux-dsl</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: If module 1 downloads data, and module 2 processes it, why not make one the client of the other? You'll need to explain further why each needs to depend on the other.

Comment: Well module 1 is pulling data from an exchange and doing some calculations with it, meanwhile data is fetched from my local time series db (which in the background does a lot of pre processing. So data is 24/7 going between the 2 modules and i'd like to keep  them seperated as they have very differend tasks. Is there a way to get this to work or would it bbe better to re-design?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two modules calling each other.

Either you merge them, or you change your design in a way that calls only go one-way, i.e. only module A calls module B but not vice versa.

Comment: Or a third module with the common communication class’s

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That is also a possibility.